# i am getting a 'Application Error' while hosting django project on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

recently i have tried to host my first django project on heroku, but i am getting the following error "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail"

this is a link of my github repository...........https://github.com/derexes292/onlinetest..........

i have put the screenshot of error and logs in the 'error screenshot' folder

[image: logs screenshot]

please help me, i have been working on this problem from a long time but i am not getting any solution.

Comment: From line number 3 of the logs, it seems that there is a problem with an import named "CCMS"

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed the git repo, your project's `Procfile` requires an update. You need to provide the correct project name instead of `CCMS.wsgi` -> `onlinetest.wsgi`,

```
web: gunicorn CCMS.wsgi --log-file -
```

to

```
web: gunicorn onlinetest.wsgi --log-file -
```

After changing `Procfile` deploy it again on Heroku. I hope this will solve your problem